# Ansible Tower Permission denied: '/var/lib/awx/projects' even when has access

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

When I try to log into Ansible Tower or navigate around, I'm getting a 500 error. The `/var/log/tower.log` shows:

```
2016-12-20 14:34:59,659 ERROR    django.request Internal Server Error: /api/v1/config/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/tower/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awx/api/views.py", line 234, in get
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awx/main/models/projects.py", line 57, in get_local_path_choices
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/awx/projects'
```

But the `/var/lib/awx/projects` directory is fully owned by the `awx` user.

```
$ ls -la /var/lib/awx/projects/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 awx awx    6 Dec 19 16:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 9 awx awx 4096 Dec 20 10:38 ..
```

Has anyone ever experienced this? What's the way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got SElinux enabled and blocking access to the file. Notice the dot at the end:

```
drwxr-xr-x.
```

Check the details with `ls -Z /var/lib/awx/projects/`.

Refer to [SELinux - Contexts Labeling Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html). Also [this answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50641/133107) might be of help.

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you! I indeed saw SELinux denying read access to the file for the `httpd` process. Execute the command from the linked answer fixed Tower. The command being: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/lib/awx/projects/`.

Thanks again! Really appreciate it.